# How to define this structure in C#

Tags: c#, generics, structure

I'm new to C# and I need to declare a variable which contain the following pattern model:

```
(44,"name") , ((7,"name", {"false", "38", "name", "name", "339"}), (10,"name", {"name", "name", "67", "name", "true", "339"}),.....(int, "name", {"name", "name", "name", "name"...}))


0 [(int,string) , ((int,string, {string, string, string, string}), (int,string, {string, string, string, string}),.....(int, string, {string, string, string, string, string, string...}))]
1 [(int,string) , ((int,string, {string, string, string}), (int,string, {string, string, string, string}),.....(int, string, {string, string, string, string, string, string...}))]
2 [(int,string) , ((int,string, {string, string, string, string, string}), (int,string, {string, string, string, string}),.....(int, string, {string, string, string, string, string, string...}))]
3 [(int,string) , ((int,string, {string, string}), (int,string, {string, string, string, string}),.....(int, string, {string, string, string, string, string, string...}))]
...

n [(int,string) , ((int,string, {string, string}), (int,string, {string, string, string, string}),.....(int, string, {string, string, string, string, string, string...}))]
```

I do not know which is the elegant solution to express / declare it using C#.
I need to cycle through variable elements and access it for modifying/editing..
Thank you!

Comment: I'm very vague on the question here; it *sounds* like an object with a child collection of some type, but it is *really* hard to tell from just a dump of fairly-meaningless values with no clear intent

Comment: Can you show non-elegant solution you want to improve and explain what you don't like in it?

Comment: I like to use a dictionary to declare the variable, but I'm not sure how to begin :) where (int,string) is TKey and the right side is the TValue ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try something along those lines:

```
class Parent
{
    int id;
    string name;
    List<Child> children;

    public Parent(int ID, string Name, List<Child> Children)
    {
        id = ID;
        name = Name;
        children = Children;
    }
}

class Child
{
    int id;
    string name;
    List<string> values;

    public Child(int ID, string Name, List<string> Values)
    {
        id = ID;
        name = Name;
        values = Values;
    }
}
```

You should first create the child objects and then add it to the parent object.
This way you can access the parent and with this you have access to all the other values you want access to.

If you need more help just let me know in the comments, I know how this can be confusing in the beginning.

Good luck!

Comment: I love you!!!! not homo! thank you very much!!! creating classes is the approach!.. I'm struggling to understand, but this is the direction!

Comment: Just let me know if you need any more help :)

Answer (score 1):

Use class, C# is an objective language so you shouldn't have problem with declaring proper methods.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-sharp-class-and-object/